# tcard is not resetting, getting null in tcardController.state Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, swipecardview

I am [tcard pkg](https://pub.dev/packages/tcard) in my project. i want reset the card in every 5 seconds automatically the length of the list is changing but the UI is not resetting, getting null in tcardController.state
Is there any other pkg, so we can achieve same functionality of this tcard pkg.

Refer to below code:-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tcard/tcard.dart';

List<Color> colors = [
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.pink,
  Colors.amber,
  Colors.cyan,
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.brown,
  Colors.teal,
];

class TCardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TCardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TCardPageState createState() => _TCardPageState();
}

class _TCardPageState extends State<TCardPage> {
  final TCardController _controller = TCardController();
  int _index = 0;
  Timer? timer;
  bool changeColor = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => sequenceApiCall());
    print(_controller.state.toString());
    // _controller.reset;
  }

  void sequenceApiCall() {
    changeColor = !changeColor;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      print('sequenceApiCall');
      if (changeColor) {
        print('changeColor');
        colors.removeAt(0);
        print('color count = ${colors.length}'); //9
      } else {
        colors.insert(0, Colors.black);
        print('black');
        print('color count = ${colors.length}'); //10
      }
      print(_controller.state.toString());
      _controller.reset();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer?.cancel();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 200),
            TCard(
              cards: cardsColor,
              controller: _controller,
              onForward: (index, info) {
                _index = index;
                print(info.direction);
                setState(() {});
              },
              onBack: (index, info) {
                _index = index;
                setState(() {});
              },
              onEnd: () {
                print('end');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.back();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Back'),
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.forward();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Forward'),
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.reset();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Reset'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(_index.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> cardsColor = List.generate(
    colors.length,
    (int index) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colors[index],
        ),
        child: Text(
          '${index + 1}',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.!!!